# Use the page picker from wordpress menu creation page

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, pages

Is it possible to use the page picker from the menu creation page on other pages in admin mode?

(This thing: [image] )

I am creation a custom page type that will show specific pages in a list, and to choose which pages to display it would be really nice to use it.

Comment: Have you seen https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know a way of re-using the page picker but you could achieve what you're trying to do with the "Post Object" field type in the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin.

> The post object field creates a select field where the choices are
>   your pages + posts + custom post types. This field is useful for
>   advanced linking to another page / post.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/